# Why d3.js works only with GeoJSON violating right-hand rule?

Tags: geojson, d3

Why d3.js works only with GeoJSON that is left-hand formatted?

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
              [
                [0, 0], [10, 0], [0, 10], [0, 0]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

is supposedly well formed and not broken - https://geojsonlint.com/ shows it as follows[image]

while d3.js shows it as a hole in the world (filled area across entire world except that area)

[image]

My, likely bungled, d3 attempt code is hosted at https://matkoniecz.github.io/wat/valid.html (with correct GeoJSON). Version with points in reverse order, raising warnings elsewhere works: https://matkoniecz.github.io/wat/map.html

What is going on here? I am likely missing something but I run out of ideas. Maybe d3 is simply not supporting GeoJSON? And all examples that I found are broken/confusing because people who made them were unaware that GeoJSON is not supported?

Code is also posted below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
      <svg width="800px" height="600px">
        <g class="generated_map" id="generated_map"></g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.6.2/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    const width = 800;
    const height = 600;
    var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
              [
                //[-179, 80], [179, 0], [179, 80], [-179, 80] // works? why?
                //[0, 0], [10, 0], [0, 10], [0, 0] // hole in the world
                [0, 0], [0, 10], [10, 0], [0, 0]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], geojson)

    var geoGenerator = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

    function update(geojson) {
      var u = d3.select('#content g.generated_map')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(geojson.features);

      u.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', geoGenerator)
        .attr("stroke", 'black')
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
    }
    update(geojson);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look on parent forum about the issue details and related explanations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311001/d3-js-drawing-geojson-incorrectly

You can also find a recipe at https://observablehq.com/@john-guerra/d3-black-box-map to always change GeoJSON winding order using Turf.js

Comment: thanks! So I will need to convert from osm JSON to geoJSON to d3.geoJSON :)